# Given a byte string S of length l, obtain the string D of length l-1 as D(i) = S(i) * S(i+1)

Tags: homework, assembly, x86

`Given a byte string S of length l, obtain the string D of length l-1 as D(i) = S(i) * S(i+1) (each element of D is the product of two consecutive elements of S).`

here is my code.

```
bits 32

global start        

extern exit
import exit msvcrt.dll  

segment data use32 class=data
    s db 1, -3, 4, 7 ; declaring the string of bytes s
    l equ $ - s - 1 ; compute the length of the string l - 1
    d times l dw 0 ; reserve l bytes for the destination string and initialize it
segment code use32 class=code
    start:
        mov ecx, l
        
        mov esi, 0
        
        jecxz end_prog
        repeat_this:
            mov al, [s + esi] ; in al - the element on the esi position
            mov dh, [s + esi + 1] ; in dh - the element after the esi position
            imul dh ; multiplying consecutive terms
            mov [d + esi], ax; put the result in d
            inc esi ; incrementing esi to go to the next position
        loop repeat_this  
    
        end_prog:
        
        push dword 0
        call [exit]
```

my question is did I make a mistake by declaring `d times l dw 0` since I know that a byte * byte = word? Is everything else okay or should I pay attention to some details that I'm missing?

Comment: You're asking whether `d` is supposed to be declared with `dw` element-size, but the quoted program-description doesn't clearly say, so as far as I can tell there's no way for us to know that. Was there originally a larger explanation or some additional context that contains such information?

Comment: no, I just wanted to know if that would be considered a mistake even if it doesn't say. also I didn't know if my program was entirely correct because of that fact. so I wanted to check and asked someone more experienced than me.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: fixed it @Reinderien, I'm sorry! :c

Comment: It's OK :) For a relatively new user this is a quite-good question for CR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Inconsistent addressing of `d`

`d` is an array of 2-byte elements (`d times l dw 0`) and `mov [d + esi], ax` indexes into it with `esi` as the offset. However, `esi` is increased by 1 every iteration, so the resulting access pattern is that the stores keep stepping half on top of the previous store, shown by such a diagram: (storing -3, -12 and 28 in sequence)

```
FD FF
   F4 FF
      1C 00
```

This is possible to do, but probably unintentional.

Normally my recommendation would be to increase the register by 2 in the loop, but `esi` is also used to index `s` so that won't work. You can change the store to double `esi` though, for example:

```
mov [d + esi*2], ax
```

Or,

```
mov [d + esi + esi], ax
```

If you change `d` to be an array of bytes then the store should be `mov [d + esi], al`, with the original address but storing only 1 byte. Storing overlapping words would put the right data in `d`, but it's strange and stores a stray byte just after the end of `d`.

## Calling `exit`

`exit` performs C library termination procedures, but the C library runtime environment wasn't used or even initialized (this code is in `start`, not `main`), so it's not necessary. It makes more sense to call `ExitProcess` (kernel32.dll), or just return (that does not work on Linux, but this is a Windows program and there it does work).

## The `loop` instruction

[`loop` is not great](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881279/how-exactly-does-the-x86-loop-instruction-work), it has some niche uses but typically it should be avoided. `jecxz` by contrast is OK, just unusual.

## Minor things

The best way to zero `esi` isn't `mov esi, 0`, it's [`xor esi, esi`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617/555045), unless the flags must not be affected.

The two loads of the current and next element of S could be merged into a single `word` load, if you want. For example `mov ax, [s + esi]` followed by `imul ah`.

Comment: thank you for the detailed comment for the program! we were taught to use loop and jecxz, but I'll try to look for better alternatives in the future!

Comment: because it forces the content of esi to be 0.

Comment: @Reinderien that's also a link to the reasons, but perhaps the double-formatting is not super clear

Comment: @harold Oh! I missed that - thank you!